# Searching for a table in table lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table in a table structure like this:

```
[1] = {
    [1] = {
        category = "WORD",
        cursor = <filtered>,
        ptype = "STATEMENT",
        ttype = "SERVICE",
        value = "service",
        <metatable> = <filtered>
    },
    [2] = {
        category = "VARIABLE",
        cursor = <filtered>,
        ptype = "STATEMENT",
        ttype = "IDENTIFIER",
        value = "TestService",
        <metatable> = <filtered>
    },
    [3] = {
        ttype = "BRACE_BLOCK",
        value = {
            [1] = { ...
...
[2] = {
    [1] = {
        category = "WORD",
        cursor = <filtered>,
        ptype = "STATEMENT",
        ttype = "SERVICE",
        value = "service",
        <metatable> = <filtered>
    },
    [2] = {
        category = "VARIABLE",
        cursor = <filtered>,
        ptype = "STATEMENT",
        ttype = "IDENTIFIER",
        value = "HelloWorld",
        <metatable> = <filtered>
    },
```

I programmed a simply loop which looks for the first table with the ttype, filtered that information out and would like to assign the rest of the tokens until the next Service starts to corresponding service. My idea looks like that:

```
 local found_service = 0
 if found_service == 0 then
 for k1, v1 in pairs (parse_tree) do
      for i=1,#v1 do
            if v1[i].ttype == "SERVICE"  then
            --Store wanted data in an object
             found_service = 1
             end  
            if (found_service == 1 and v1[i].ttype ~= "SERVICE") then
            -- ->assign the rest to last found service
            end
            if found_service == 1 and v1[i].ttype == "SERVICE" then
            -- ->Found the next service -->starting over
            found_service = 0
            end
        end    
   end
 end
```

The problem is that I stuck at index i, and v1[i] is a "SERVICE", so he enters directly the last if-clause, too. How do I end one loop-iteration (after the first if-clause). Or ist there a much better way to do this?

Thanks in advise.
Theo

Comment: Use a `goto` to some `::label::`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your general idea, but here is the answer of how to skip loop body on first `"SERVICE"` capture event.

```
 local found_service = 0
 if found_service == 0 then
 for k1, v1 in pairs (parse_tree) do
      for i=1,#v1 do
            if (found_service == 0 and v1[i].ttype == "SERVICE")  then
                --Store wanted data in an object
                found_service = 1
            else
                if (found_service == 1 and v1[i].ttype ~= "SERVICE") then
                    -- ->assign the rest to last found service
                end
                if found_service == 1 and v1[i].ttype == "SERVICE" then
                    -- ->Found the next service -->starting over
                    found_service = 0
                end
             end  
        end    
   end
 end
```

But I'm still don't get it what should be done on current record not `"SERVICE"` and `found_service == 0`. By the way, in my answer after `found_service` become 0 in third `if`, the first `if` could be `true` again.

If your idea is to build some kind of vector like:
SERVICE_1 (other ttype tables until next SERVICE)
SERVICE_2 (other ttype tables until next SERVICE)
...

In that case code could be:

```
 local found_service = 0
 if found_service == 0 then
 for k1, v1 in pairs (parse_tree) do
      for i=1,#v1 do
            if (found_service == 0 and v1[i].ttype == "SERVICE")  then
                --Store wanted data in an object
                found_service = 1
                current_service = v1[i]
            else
                if (found_service == 1 and v1[i].ttype ~= "SERVICE") then
                    -- ->assign the rest to last found service
                end
                if found_service == 1 and v1[i].ttype == "SERVICE" then
                    -- ->Found the next service -->starting over
                    current_service = v1[i]
                end
             end  
        end    
   end
 end
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked great for me.